# how can i use AppFigures api to get the data of downloads stats of my application using curl command

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails

Hey all i am using this [AppFigures api](http://docs.appfigures.com/) to get the data of downloads stats of my ios application using curl command, but its not working

I am trying this

```
curl -u'username:password' Https://api.appfigures.com/v1.1/sales/{product}/{2010-5-5}/{2013-5-5}/?data_source={daily}&products={0123654}
```

It returns an empty hash

```
> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer as i was doing stupid thing. The command i was trying is correct but I had to provide my itunes connect account information to AppFigures so that it can authorize and synchronize my itunes account with my appfigures account.